Is LTspice AC analysis trustworthy at RF when using low impedance sources?
I'm an amateur at circuit design but I've been reading a lot and trying my best. I've edited the question to try to make the main problem more coherent and add a simple schematic and plots.



My setup is conventional- 500 mV 100 kHz load into a correctly biased common-emitter amplifier with shunt feedback and emitter degeneration, with a 50 Ω resistor at the output, with correctly selected decoupling capacitors of 15.9 µF and a LPF capacitor of 10 pF.
The transistor in question has a hFE of 133 and is relatively tolerant of voltage variances and current supply. As depicted with the resistors used, the collector voltage is about 4v, base voltage about 1.5, base current about 230uA with a 100uA swing each way, emitter current about 18mA with a swing of about 15mA each way. the swing is is also the current being pushed over C4 and through the load resistor.
I must say I absolutely fear math but I think i understand transistor logic a little bit and was able to bias this not too poorly.
Now, the problem is When the source is configured with Rser=50, the gain is wherever you'd expect it to be, but when Rser is set to 0.1 or smaller(to simulate closed loop gain), the S21 metric drops, usually to -50 dBm or something like this. Transient analysis does not reflect this- voltage at output measured in transient peak to peak is larger than input and input is close to or equal to configured voltage.
Should I trust my transient readings? See attached images.
Older thread that seems related:
LTSpice divergence between AC analysis and transient analysis for low frequency gain
Some other dumb questions I have which are NOT about AC analysis:
Based on my limited training, my source is 500 mV and I am told to keep the gain down and get the linearity up. 500 mV is very convenient for doing mental calculations but represents an unusual power level at HF.
Should I instead use the largest power I expect to see? More on this.
I'm working at shortwave, and would like to optimize for shortwave. It seems that the realistic typical modern noise floor on most of shortwave is not lower around than -122 dBm (500 nV), and the realistic maximum amplitude for signals over this noise floor is +80 dBm, which translates to -40 dBm or about 6 mV. The minimum signals I want to amplify are near the noise floor, but depending on how the transistor is biased, it doesn't handle these very well in transient simulation.
I have tried a few different configurations and what I've found is that the hotter it's driven the better the simulation seems to handle faint signal amplification. For a wideband RF amplifier, do I need to test at the faint voltage as well to make sure the behavior remains linear?
With regards to testing this in LTspice, what voltages should I be using? should I be using a -2 dB 500 mV signal? should I use something closer to 6 mV? With regards to my SFDR, I am being advised I should aim for over 100, but this seems difficult to accomplish and yet still have meaningful gain. Is it more realistic that I aim for around 77-80?

LTspice just works. If you know what it is and does and doesn't do. I see no specific schematics showing a case you feel is inexplicable. I see words.  And I may or may not follow them accurately. But I do see incorrect assumptions in your writing. So I conclude you are not the best person to judge the tool. Can you include a specific circuit, say the one that meets your expectations with a 50 Ohm source but doesn't with a 0.1 Ohm source? Start there?

It's as trustworthy as the models you use. It's a standard GIGO situation, garbage in, garbage out.

Reading through a dozen paragraphs seems a bit overkill for a basic amplifier or simulation question -- if you could simplify your question (perhaps in a separate thread now that there is an existing answer), and include a schematic, that would greatly motivate useful and topical answers to your question. Cheers!

You need to make sure you are modeling the real world, include parasitics in the model

What version of LTSpice are you using? I have 17.1.8 and s21() is not a documented built-in function, so it's not clear to me how it is calculated. It doesn't make sense to me to have an s21() function with only one source as an argument and no way to specify which node or load is taken as the output, but maybe there are some undocumented assumptions being made. Given that there is no documentation for the s21() function, I'd just ignore it and calculate the gain using measurements of the well-defined node voltages and branch currents in the circuit.

The other charts seem to agree reasonably well, with the transient showing 0.5 V in giving about 0.7 V out or gain of about 1.4x; while the AC analysis shows a gain about halfway between 0 and 7 dB. If you put markers on the plots or at least zoomed them in to reasonable scales, it would be much easier to tell if there is any real discrepency or not.

AC and transient analysis agree, you have around 4dB (voltage) gain. Calculating the gain with 20 log ( Rload / (R2 + 25mV/Ic)) gives the same result, about 4dB. By the way, the amp is not really suited as a small loop amplifier, it has not the proper input impedance and the gain is too low.


is ltspice AC analysis trustworthy at RF when using low impedance sources?

The accuracy of an LTSpice analysis depends entirely on the accuracy of the model you provide it. Did you include all relevant parasitics? Are your device models accurate at the operating points where you'll operate the circuit?
In the case of AC analysis, the analysis assumes without checking that the circuit behaves linearly. If you drive the circuit hard enough to excite nonlinear behavior, the AC analysis can't predict that and doesn't try.

My setup is conventional- 500mV 100kHz load ...

In modern technology, 100 kHz is at the low end of what counts as RF. Of course you could deliberately design a component that has significant parasitics at 100 kHz, but the real problems of RF design with unexpected parasitics typically come in the upper 10's or 100's of MHz.

the transistors also impose other forms of noise and the total noise figure indicated is around 1db when they're being driven hard.

If you want to simulate noise behavior in LTSpice, you can, but you will essentially have to fully understand the noise sources in your circuit and build the model for them manually.

With regards to testing this in LTSpice, what voltages should I be using? should I be using a -2db 500mv signal? should I use something closer to 6mV and aim to reach enough SFDR for 80db of signals?

As mentioned above, AC analysis assumes (and doesn't check) that the circuit is linear. The solution for 500 mV will just be 1/2 of the solution for 1 V. The solution for 6 mV input will just be .006 times the solution for 1 V. So it's conventional to just run the simulation with 1 V or 1 A inputs, and then scale the results to predict results at other levels.

Should I also be testing at 500nV and ensuring that the amplifier is stable at this voltage, or is testing with a tiny little voltage not representative of behavior when evaluating the stability of the amplifier when amplifying near the noise floor?


Again, 500 nV will just give \$5\times 10^{-7}\$ times the solution for 1 V.

Testing for stability typically requires "breaking the loop" and injecting a signal at a point that might not be the input point used in normal operation. Stability doesn't depend on what the input level is. A full explanation of stability analysis is beyond the scope of a single answer here.



This is unfortunantly not correct. Depending on how hot the transistor is run, it either will or wont offer stable behavior at very small voltages. Secondly, the greater the voltage swing of the signal, the greater the distortion possible due to current swing in the transistor, and therefore it alters SFDR(although no or almost no variation between 500nV and 3mV, ie, the smaller, the less impact)

@HFGCS, I am well aware that large signals can cause distortion in amplifiers. But an AC analysis in LTSpice (or any other SPICE) will tell you nothing about it. It assumes (and doesn't check, as I said in my answer) that the circuit is linear and therefore that no distortion occurs. If you are interested in distortion, you can not use a SPICE AC analysis to study it. You can use a transient (TRAN) analysis, but you didn't ask about that.

I did ask. I asked if i should trust transient over AC. IF transient says Vout is 1Vptp, then my amplification factor is 2, and S21(ac) says otherwise, should I trust the transient? that is the whole question.

Transient and AC Analysis need to agree with each other. If you get different gain values then something is wrong with your circuit, analysis setup or assessment of the reported results. Post the schematic of your amp if you are looking for help.

@Raonoke To be fair, the old question linked in this question’s text turned out to be an actual SPICE bug. So this is why the simulator integrity is being questioned. Regardless, I agree with you and there’s no way for us to find out for sure unless the questioner posts a schematic and/or more specific and detailed example.

@HFGCS I think you need to edit your question with more details/specifics and hopefully a schematic for us to determine what’s going on. Otherwise, I believe this answer does a good job addressing the generalities.
